# Is there any way to detect when a contact has been merged?

Tags: google-contacts-api

I'm developing an app that syncs contact data from Google Contacts to other sources. I'm having difficulty detecting when contacts have been merged in Google. When contacts are merged, one of the contacts persists, while the other one seems to be deleted (I can trace it by id using ContactEntry.hasDeleted). Is there a way to identify when the deleted contact has in fact been merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you check the [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) there is no guides here that can determine if the contacts have been merged. Just check this documentation for you to know the only possible things right now that you can do with this API.

If you want this feature, I suggest you to create a [feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/) about it.

For more information, check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389180/google-data-api-merge-contacts).

Comment: This is great, thanks @KENdi. I did submit the feature request to Google, here for whoever is interested: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5134&thanks=5134&ts=1486726699