# How to merge google contacts datas by phone number and/or e-mail?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-contacts-api

Is there a best practice to merge contacts?

My phone is connected to the Google account, so it sync with GMail contacts. I can download with Google API PHP client my contact datas. But I have contacts from my phone, from skype and from viber, facebook, etc. So I have multiple contacts for my friends.

It looks like this:

Contact #1:

```
Name: Friend One
Phone number: +1234567890
E-mail: friend-one@example.com
```

Contact #2:

```
Name: One Friend
Phone number:
E-mail: friend-one@example.com
E-mail: one-friend@example.com
```

Contact #3:

```
Name: Uncle Joe
Phone number: +9876543210
Phone number: +1234567890
E-mail: unclejoe@example.com
```

Is there a best prctice in PHP to merge this three contacts into one, what is looks like this:

```
Name: Friend One
Nickname: Uncle Joe
Phone number: +1234567890
Phone number: +9876543210
E-mail: friend-one@example.com
E-mail: one-friend@example.com
E-mail: unclejoe@example.com
```

It's irrelevant whichwas is the "Name" or "Nickname", I just need to keep the datas.

Is there a best practice to merge contacts?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) there is no guides here that can merge the two contacts. Just check this documentation for you to know the only possible things right now that you can do with this API.

If you want this feature, I suggest you to create a [feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/) about it.

For more information, check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389180/google-data-api-merge-contacts).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to use the Google Contacts API to merge. I can merge datas after I downloaded that. So I'm looking for a PHP solution, not a Google Contacts API solution.